# Resiliance4j - retry custom IntervalFunction with multiple waitDuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry, resilience4j

Resilience4j version: 1.4.0
Java version: 11

I want to achieve the exact thing mentioned here at : https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry#use-a-custom-intervalfunction

*If you don't want to use a fixed wait duration between retry attempts, you can configure an IntervalFunction which is used instead to calculate the wait duration for every attempt.*

Do we need to configure it in yml file ? or do we need to overwrite IntervalFunction ?
I need to have 3 retries exponentially, each with different wait duration, for eg : 1st retry should be after 30 sec, 2nd retry after 45 min, 3rd retry should be after 2hrs. Where to configure these timestamps ? I am newbie, please suggest.

Service class:

```
@Retry(name = "retryService1", fallbackMethod = "retryfallback")
@Override
public String customerRegistration(DTO dto) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String response = restTemplate("/register/customer", dto, String.class); // this throws 500 error code
    return response ;
}

public String retryfallback(DTO dto, Throwable t) {
    logger.error("Inside retryfallback, cause - {} {}", t.toString(), new Date());
    return "Inside retryfallback method. Some error occurred while calling service for customer registration";
}
```

application.yml

```
resilience4j.retry.instances:
    retryService1:
      maxRetryAttempts: 3
      waitDuration: 10s
      enableExponentialBackoff: true
      exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's currently only possible by using a RetryConfigCustomizer.

```
@Bean
public RetryConfigCustomizertestCustomizer() {
    return RetryConfigCustomizer
        .of("retryService1", builder -> builder.intervalFunction(intervalWithExponentialBackoff));
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please give me some more details about it. Don't have sufficient document about it. I am wondering how can i pass multiple intervals or waitDurations ? Builder accepts only 1 duration, builder -> builder.intervalFunction(IntervalFunction.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2))))

Comment: You can implement your own IntervalFunction. It's an interface. You can provide any class. You dont have to use our builder.